# Allocating with palloc

Tags: postgresql, odbc

This is part of a postgres extension and I'm trying to understand why the line of code below gives me this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 1073741824
```

[This](https://github.com/adunstan/odbc_fdw/commit/5929e7793023584b2eb7acf954256d87f3bf642a) code is a odbc fdw for postgres; I get that error when I use the extension to create a sql server foreign table; the problem begins when a sql server column is declared as nvarchar(max), according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) the maximum size of a nvarchar(max) is 1073741823. The code tries to do basically this:

```
char * buf;

//varsize contains the max size of nvarchar(max)

buf = (char *)palloc(sizeof(char) * (varsize + 1));
```

What is palloc exactly doing so you can't allocate more than 1073741823 in a pointer? it's not like the size exceeds a integer range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the details in [this comment](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/ee943004466418595363d567f18c053bae407792/src/include/utils/memutils.h#L23), but the TL;DR is that TOAST isn't capable of storing something larger than 1GB-1B in size, so trying to palloc it is pretty pointless. There's a few places that make use of MemoryContextAllocHuge(), but it sounds like that won't help you.